Render Blocking Resources affecting only PAges and not the Posts in wordpress
Some of the website test tools are showing the render blocking resources ( a css file from litespeed cache plugin) is hindering the load speed of the website. It is only the Urls related to the pages which trigger this warning, all the urls related to the posts are free from it.
The problem had started after the latest wordpress 6.5.3 update.
Google page speed score does not exhibit this warning though, I get this on Keycdn speed test.
I have already conducted all the basic possible checks which could be related to this problem:
I use GEnerate PRess theme- Free version.
I use Litespeed cache plugin for page optimization and Super Page Cache for Cloudflare plugin for page catching and has ensured caching is working properly.
My website is running on a vps server and is way behind full use of the available resources on the same.
I use memcache and redis cache as object cache, along with varnish cache and Opcache as server level cache mechanisms.
.
Have checked in the plugin, theme compatibility issues, with no such problems indicated.
I just one on real wp cron jon on my wordpress site.
O regularly optimize my database with a database plugin.
I USe DNS and CDN serves from cloudflare, free plan.
I have checked the apache server logs and rectified the php fatal errors. infact the ranking score went up after that.
THE problem is only with pages and not the Posts on the website.
Can anyone help with the same.
